# Why does this while loop act this way?

Tags: java, while-loop

```
    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;

    while (i < 4) {

        j += i;

        i++;

    }

    System.out.println("i = " + i);
    System.out.println("j = " + j);
```

I have the following above and I am trying to figure out how it works. I am new to java so I do not know how to debug my code yet. The output of this program says that i = 4 and j = 7. However the condition of the while loop should only execute when i < 4. Why does it execute when i = 4? I tried changing the condition to i <= 4 and it outputs i = 5. What am I missing here?

Comment: The values of `j` and `i` are changed the *last* time the condition is true (and the loop was run).

Comment: It doesn't execute when `i == 4`. `i` has to `== 4` to get the loop to terminate. It terminates when `i == 4`, so that's the value of `i` when you're done.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java, it is the samein every language I am aware of, except Asembly

Comment: Think about what would happen if you change the condition to `i < 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i = 1

is 1 less than 4? Yes, so loop.

add one to i so now i = 2.

is 2 less than 4?  Yes, so loop.

add one to i so now i = 3.

is 3 less than 4?  Yes, so loop.

add one to i so now **i = 4**.

is 4 less than 4?  No, leave the loop.

Print the value of i which is 4.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the steps. I figured that it does not execute when i = 4 but i still gets incremented.

Answer (score 3):

The loop counter will be incremented for every iteration through the loop. When the counter has been incremented past 3 (when it's equal to 4) the loop will stop. The loop won't run when the counter is 4, but the counter was still incremented to 4

Answer (score 0):

You enter the loop when `i=3`. Inside the loop, you increment i by 1 (`i++`). At the end of that iteration, you check if `i<4`, which it is not, because `i=4`.